# Writing in Tamil(தமிழ் ) Latex

Tags: luatex, tamil

Right now, I have been sketching out my thesis. According to our university rules, we have to keep **Tamil version of synopsis** in our thesis. I have been using Texmaker (LualaTEX). Can someone guide me how to invoke Tamil language in a particular section without disturbing other section contents.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: There are several questions under the tag [tag:tamil].  Does one of them help you out?

Comment: @Teepeemm Suggestions of Javier Bezos helped me to address the issue I was facing. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Akshar Unicode" is the font that helped me to being tamil output beautifully.

Source file

```
\documentclass{article}
%Always start xelatex files with these in preamble. This helps in defining the script and fonts
\usepackage{fontspec}
%Set the main languge next as main font.
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Lohit Hindi}

%Set rest of the languages l;ike this. Experiment a bit. script=punjabi did not work. Replaced with gurmukhi and it works.

\newfontfamily{\tam}[Script=Tamil]{Akshar Unicode}
\newfontfamily{\tel}[Script=Telugu]{Akshar Unicode}
\newfontfamily{\kan}[Script=Kannada]{Mallige}
\newfontfamily{\Guja}[Script=Gujarati]{Lohit Gujarati}
\newfontfamily{\ben}[Script=Bengali]{Lohit Bengali}
\newfontfamily{\Punj}[Script=Gurmukhi]{Lohit Punjabi}

%English does not need any script specifiction! Just define the font.
\newfontfamily{\eng}{Arial}
\begin{document}
%No need to define script as this is the manin font set. Like defalut.
नमो पकवते नारायणाय! \\
%Switch language like this. { begins the changed line. \xxx denotes the switched  language. Use the same definition as denoted in preamble. } will end the switch and default to main unless again specified.
{\tel నమో పకవతే నారాయణాయ!}\\
{\kan ನಮೋ ಪಕವತೇ ನಾರಾಯಣಾಯ
}\\
{\Guja નમો પકવતે નારાયણાય!}\\
{\Punj ਨਮੋ ਪਕਵਤੇ ਨਾਰਾਯਣਾਯ!}\\
{\ben নমো পকবতে নারায়ণায়!}\\
{\tam நமோ பகவதே நாராயணாய!}\\

{\eng namo bhagavate naraayanaaya}\\
%the next line does not begin liekt he ones above. so it defaults to mainfont which is devanagari.
शुभम।
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: latex output in indic languages]

Wrote about the same here too

https://goinggnu.wordpress.com/2013/06/10/indian-languages-in-latex/

Comment: Thank you. Wrt the question can you please add, how to have e.g. English and Tamil in different sections, i.e. with focus on the synopsis?

Comment: @tshrinivasan Thanks for the suggestion. I was able to solve issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements are somewhat vague, and without an MWE it’s not easy to provide a proper answer, but here's a starting point:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\babelfont[tamil]{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]{FreeSerif}

\begin{document}

\section{English}

A section in English.

\section{Tamil}

\begin{otherlanguage}{tamil}
நூல் என்பது எண்ணப் பதிவாகிய கருத்துகளை எழுத்து உருவில் காட்டும் ஒரு கருவி.
\end{otherlanguage}

\section{English}

Another section in English.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. It works! Now I am able to render the Tamil contents without any trouble. (In future will post the questions with working examples!)